# gcc preprocessor: how to escape quotes in an argument

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use gcc preprocessor for its macro expansion capabilities (I'm not trying to produce code).

I have a macro — MY_MACRO — that needs to get an argument that has double quotes inside
As you can see, the preprocessor produces an error: unterminated argument list

Is there a way to escape the quotes?

```
#define MY_MACRO(X)
MY_MACRO(prefix"suffix)
```

For example:

```
$ gcc -E -P -w a.txt
error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "MY_MACRO"
$
```

Comment: "needs to get an argument that has double quotes inside" Why? What are you planning to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor works on C source code. A lone `"` is not valid C, so the cpp rejects it. You can cpp for other purposes only if you're willing to stick to the C syntax rules.

`m4` is a general-purpose macro-processor and standard installed on anything Unix-like, though nobody likes it. There aren't many alternatives.

Comment: I can imagine situations where this example can be used to create a compiling c code.